# Why are there no free resources on exploit development on macOS?

Tags: exploit, macos, exploit-development

There are many resources on Linux exploit development, but I cannot find any resources targeting macOS, except for some bad ones on YouTube.

Why are there no write-ups on macOS exploitation techniques, taking into account the Mach-O file format and the BSD-based kernel?

Comment: I think your search terms might be off. When I search for "OSX exploit development" I get full-blown courses covering this topic...

Comment: Yes, paid courses. Can you find blogs or equivalent, like it is the case for Windows?

Comment: I suspect that the organizations who are doing professional OSX exploitation are not publishing their results or techniques.

Answer (score 0):

A new exploit for iOS/macOS discussed here — https://blog.zecops.com/vulnerabilities/analysis-and-reproduction-of-cve-2019-7286/

Here also is another older blog on macOS Mach-O targeting — https://www.offensive-security.com/vulndev/evocam-remote-buffer-overflow-on-osx/

Comment: Thank you - still the amount of resources is next to nothing compared to Windows/Linux material.

Comment: The resources are just in different places, under the auspice of Obj-C/Cocoa development instead of classic pen tester resources. Check out books like The Complete Friday Q&A or the newosxbook.com website and training.

Comment: ahh, that  explains things. If you know other canonical resources, please add them 